# How to create our own marker for Augmented Reality in iOS technology?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, augmented-reality, marker

I am new in AR technology, I have researched and come to know that AR works upon marker detection technology.

I found some sample code with vuforia, string, ARKit, etc.

But how they are detecting for particular marker that I am not able to fetch yet.

So my main questions are:

- How to create our own marker (for iOS) (Sample code/link would be helpful)?
- How to detect that particular marker using the camera to place our AR object?

Let me know if you require any more details.

Any help/information would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this one?

[Augmented reality on the iPhone using NyARToolkit](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/07/01/augmented-reality-on-the-iphone-using-nyartoolkit-w-code/)

Also I found some sample code here:
https://github.com/kamend/iPhone-Stuff

Comment: I am looking for such tutorial where i can identify the current object shown on camera. Like if the object is human hand then do particular thing. 
I hope my requirement is kind of clearer now.

Comment: Sorry, that makes sense when I'm reading a second time. I've changed my answer =)

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this requirement?

Comment: I thought that was what the frameworks mentioned were for, i.e. the ones you mention like vuforia and ARKit. And also NYARToolkit? They will help you with identifying the markers, will they not?

Comment: github link is broken .if any other source code or suggestion please tell me ?